# Serving testpage while running django on nginx

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx

[image]

I'm working through https://serversforhackers.com/video/letsencrypt-for-free-easy-ssl-certificates and https://certbot.eff.org/docs/intro.html , trying to add  an ssl certificate to my site (django 1.8 on nginx on ubuntu 16.04). I want to be able to serve a test page from my server. My nginx document root is at /var/www/html.

```
deploy@server:/var/www$ ll html/
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Apr 26 21:17 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Apr 25 16:27 ../
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root  4096 Apr 27 11:16 .well-known/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11321 Jun 21  2016 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   612 Feb  6 16:43 index.nginx-debian.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11321 Apr 26 21:17 test.html
```

nginx has has 2 config files. The first is default and has the following location block:

```
    location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            allow all;
    }
```

The second is:

```
# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example:
server {
    #listen 80;
    listen 80  ;
    listen [::]:80  ;
    listen 443 ssl http2  ;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2  ;


    server_name  example.org www.example.org;
    include snippets/ssl-example.org.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/deploy/example3;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/run/uwsgi/example.sock;
    }

location ~* (?:^|/)\.  {
    allow all;
}

location ^~ /\.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
```

I want to be able to serve the test page by using:

```
http://example.com/test.html
```

Instead I get the screenshot above. How can I configure nginx or django to allow the test page to be served?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the "allow all" directives. Where is the rest of the configuration, in particular the alias that serves Django?

Comment: I've added the full file above.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is not in the nginx configuration, but in the `urls.py` configuration. According to the screenshot, you haven't configured the url pattern `r'^test.html$'` that would match the URL you're trying to access.

You can find more information about configuring urls in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/).

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I don't believe its correct, because as an example the certbot documentation makes no mention of having to configure urls.py. Also please see https://www.abidibo.net/blog/2016/10/07/securing-django-lets-encrypt/